# How to increase volume on Android

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

I'm using AudioTrack to stream audio:

```
track = new AudioTrack( AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,
            SAMPLE_RATE, 
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,  
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 
            1600*2*2,                          
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

In some miracles way the UI is working without doing any thing and when I press the volume buttons the volume UI is going up and down but even when the volume is on 100% it is very low.
Please advice.
10xs,
Nahum

EDIT: This is different from previous posts because the device is showing that the volume is at 100% but it is not!

Comment: The volume UI is raising the volume of a different stream.  Use the direct API to set the volumeof the stream you want, or play on another stream.

Comment: You are right. Tablets don't have STREAM_VOICE_CALL.